# How Do I Call An Array Written in My Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Greeting all
I would like to create an array in my model and then reference it later from a view or a helper.  How do I do this?

This is in my Events model.  Users can select a lunch type(1,2,3) for the event.  Instead of hard-coding sandwich names, which can change, in my view, I thought I would keep the names in one place (model) then reference the name based on the lunch type chosen.

```
SANDWICHES = { 1 => 'Turkey', 2 => 'Veggie', 3 => 'Roast Beef' }
```

How do I call this from another script in my app like a view or a helper?

```
Event.SANDWICHES[1] does not work
event_obj.SANDWICHES[1] does not work
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a constant here to store your data. Better to use an object to represent those sandwiches. Use an instance variable to store the different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a constant and you need to access it with `Event::SANDWICHES`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I actually stumbled across it shortly after asking.  I also realized I can put the array in a method and call it that way.  Sigh--Mondays!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here is not a Model (in the rails way), it's simply a constant.

If you don't want to create an actual Model with its own database table, you could pull this out into a helper.

Such as `fillings_helper.rb`

```
def fillings
 %q{Turkey, Veggie, Roast Beef}
end
```

Then you can use it in your views for a select box by passing in fillings

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

You would need to set up a text field in your Event model to accept a string for fillings.

This isn't necessarily the best way from a database normalisation perspective, but it will do what you're asking for.